# Loading files from subfolder of the resources folder in Java

Tags: java, file, java-module

I have a problem loading files from a subfolder in the resources folder of my IntelliJ Java 15 Gradle Project...

A representation of my project structure:

```
src/main/
├── java/
│   ├── AllMyClasses.java ... ... ...
│   └── module-info.java
└── resources/
    ├── text.txt
    └── img/
        └── favicon.png
```

And the relevant snippet of my code:

```java
URL file = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("img/favicon.png");
URL file1 = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("text.txt");
System.out.println(file);
System.out.println(file1);
```

The output:

```
null
file:/C:/Users/MyUser/IdeaProjects/MyProject/build/resources/main/text.txt
```

Why does java only recognize the files DIRECTLY in the resources folder and not those in subfolders? How can I make my program also recognize those inside a subfolder?

Thanks to everyone who can help :)

Comment: This really should work. There is nothing wrong with your code. Are you sure that there is no typo or the like involved? Or maybe your jar does not actually contain the file you're trying to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your version is not working but here is what I use:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/favicon.png");
```

Note: '/' in "/img" is necessary if your class is not in a default package
(which it should not be)

Comment: Omg this did it for me. I forgot the '/'. Thats weird though, because the problem only emerged after I added a module-info.java.... Before, I literally had no problems. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: oh nice, glad I helped. (ps. you can mark this as an answer, if you think this will help others too)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you make use of either of the two as below will solve your issue.

1. InputStream in = FileInputStream(PathOfYourFile)
2. API's available in Paths class available in java.nio.file package.