# Getting resources from a subdirectory (in modular Java)

Tags: java, file

I'm going to ask a question that seems to duplicate quite a few existing ones, but none of the answers I've found seem to solve the problem for me.

Consider the following class:

```
package resources;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("toplevel.txt"));
        System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/sub/nested.txt"));
    }
}
```

in a modular project with `module-info`:

```
module resources {
    exports resources;
}
```

and a target directory structure consisting of just three files:

```
resources/Main.class
sub/nested.txt
toplevel.txt
```

The output is:

```
file:/C:/Eclipse/workspace-2023-03/resources/bin/toplevel.txt
null
```

Obviously the path `/C:/Eclipse/workspace-2023-03/resources/bin/` is the one to my target directory. Why isn't the resource `/sub/nested.txt` found?

I'm using JDK 17 in Eclipse. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947154/loading-files-from-subfolder-of-the-resources-folder-in-java) (among others) suggests the above should work, but it simply doesn't. What am I overlooking?

*EDIT*: The original question did not specifically refer to a modular project. @yshavit's answer is correct for a non-modular one, but not for a modular one.

Comment: System resource stuff always confuses me, tbh. But, have you tried removing the prefix `/` from the second path (so just `sub/nested.txt`)? You don't have it in the first path, after all. I suspect that the first path looks for a file relative to your target dir, while the second path is looking for a file relative to the root of your whole filesystem. (Note that in the question you linked, they do not have that prefix `/`.)

Comment: Try also `System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("/sub/nested.txt"));`

Comment: @yshavit is right, if you read the documentation of getSystemResource it explains better. Just use `sub/nested.txt` and it should work.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks for the confirmation! I'll repost my comment as an answer, then. Worst case, it's wrong and I'll get downvoted :-p

Comment: @g00se unfortunately that makes the problem worse, trying to load the resources via Main.class makes both of them fail

Comment: @yshavit in the question I linked, the solution was to add that slash. It supposedly doesn't refer to the the root of the file system, but the root of the items on the classpath

Comment: *@g00se unfortunately that makes the problem worse, trying to load the resources via Main.class makes both of them fail* Works fine for me

Comment: [Here](https://technojeeves.com/tech/resource-demo.jar) is a jar that prints out what you want and contains also the source code

Comment: @Arend Ah, I see. Unfortunately I've been out of the Java game for long enough that I don't really know about the module stuff anymore, so I'm at a loss now. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your prefix slash:

```
System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/sub/nested.txt"));
                                                 ⬆︎
```

Java's handling of system resources can be confusing, especially with regards to that prefix slash. But, note that you don't have it on the `getSystemResource` call that is working.

Remove that, and it should work:

```
System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("sub/nested.txt"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This works indeed, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my actual problem, which for the sake of this question I simplified: namely, if the problem is modular then sub/nested.txt fails to load, either with or without initial slash. I will edit my question so that it refers to that specific case.